# FreeIPA Server Error - ipa: ERROR: No valid Negotiate header in server response

Tags: kerberos, freeipa

I have recently installed FreeIPA on RHEL7. This seems to be running well for few hours and then calls to ipa starts to fail with the following error.

```
ipa: ERROR: No valid Negotiate header in server response
================================================== 
[root ~]# ipa -v user-find --all 
ipa: INFO: trying https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ipa/json
ipa: INFO: [try 1]: Forwarding 'user_find/1' to json server 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ipa/json'
ipa: ERROR: No valid Negotiate header in server response
-=================================================

[I have masked the hostnames with 'xxx']
```

In /var/log/httpd/error_log - I see the following error.

```
[Thu Dec 14 15:50:23.413286 2017] [auth_gssapi:error] [pid 10694] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50198] GSS ERROR In Negotiate Auth: gss_accept_sec_context() failed: [Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information ( Request ticket server HTTP/xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx@EC2.INTERNAL kvno 2 not found in keytab; keytab is likely out of date)], referer: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ipa/xml
```

What is the possible cause? Looks like some misconfiguration.

Comment: Is this reproducible?  Meaning, does everything work OK after your restart FreeIPA, only to have calls start to fail again after a few hours?

Comment: What exact version of FreeIPA are you running?  Latest is 4.5.3.

Comment: did you figure out the root cause?